# Find BLUE of $\gamma-\phi$

Tags: statistics, estimation

Consider the following model:
$$y_1 = \theta + \gamma + \epsilon_1$$
$$y_2 = \theta + \phi + \epsilon_2$$
$$y_3 = 2\theta + \phi + \gamma + \epsilon_3$$
$$y_4 = \phi − \gamma + \epsilon_4$$
where $\epsilon_i$ are uncorrelated having mean $\theta$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Show that $\gamma − \phi$ is estimable. What is its BLUE?

***MY ATTEMPT :***

I have shown $\gamma-\phi$ is estimable.

$\rightarrow$ Ok so we have to minimise $\Phi=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\gamma-\phi-\alpha-\beta^TY)^2$ Where $\alpha+\beta^TY$ is best linear predictor of $\gamma-\phi$. With $\beta^T=[\beta_1, \beta_2,\beta_3, \beta_4]$

Now $\Phi=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\beta^TY)^2+(\gamma-\phi-\alpha)^2$

For $\Phi$ to be minimum, $\hat{\alpha}=\gamma -\phi$

So $\Phi=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\beta^TYY^T\beta)$

Now how to find $\beta$ to minimise $Y$? (On a side note, whatever I have done is correct or are there any errors?)

Comment: ISI Bangalore e?

Comment: Me at ISI Kolkata..

Comment: never mind. Which year ?

Comment: LOL.. Me 2nd year!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49135/discussion-between-arghya-chakraborty-and-qwerty).